# Filtering form results with a combo box in microsoft access

Tags: ms-access, combobox, macros

Ok so I've been trying to look for a solution to this since I'm new to access but can't find anything (seriously no one has experienced this problem?)

***Here's the problem:***

I'm trying to filter the data in my **CustomerSearch form** by last name using a combo box which includes all the last names in my **Customer table**.

Using an "**After Update**" event macro, I use the "**ApplyFilter**" action and input the "**Where Condition**" with the following lines with different results:

(1)  [LastName]=[Forms]![CustomerSearch]![cboLastNameSearch]
--> gives me blank results

(2)  [LastName]=[cboLastNameSearch]
--> a popup appears every time I use the combo box asking for a last name input, which defeats the purpose of making the combo box in the first place.

where cboLastNameSearch is the name of the combo box.

Could anyone please kindly explain why (1) doesn't work, and how to improve on (2) so the popup stops showing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"[LastName]='" & [Forms]![CustomerSearch]![cboLastNameSearch] & "'"
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, but after trying out your code I end up getting all of my customers as if no filters have been applied. I'm not sure if there's anything wrong with my table since I'm still new to this though.

Comment: Nvm I found out it was my mistake after all. When creating the combo box, I was using the Last Name field in my Customer table, and by doing that I was actually using the Primary Key values as a filter instead of the Last Name string. I just created a new query to obtain only the last names from  the Customer table and used it as choices for the combo box and everything turned out fine.